# how to use user input array in heap sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, heap, heapsort

I'm a beginner so please excuse me if it is a dumb question.
I am trying to code a heap sort that takes input from user in an array and heap sorts it but i can not find a way to implement user input array in my code.
at the end, in the main function, i have to use array arr[]={} but i either have to define the elements or the number of elements so it creates zeros if i define the array as arr[10]={}
here is the code :

```
// Heap Sort in C++

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i) {
// Find largest among root, left child and right child
int largest = i;
int left = 2 * i + 1;
int right = 2 * i + 2;

if (left < n && arr[left] > arr[largest])
    largest = left;

if (right < n && arr[right] > arr[largest])
    largest = right;

// Swap and continue heapifying if root is not largest
if (largest != i) {
    swap(arr[i], arr[largest]);
    heapify(arr, n, largest);
}
}

// main function to do heap sort
void heapSort(int arr[], int n) {
// Build max heap
for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    heapify(arr, n, i);

// Heap sort
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

    // Heapify root element to get highest element at root again
    heapify(arr, i, 0);
}
}

// Print an array
void printArray(int arr[], int n) {
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
cout << "\n";
}

// Driver code
int main() {

int arr[10] = { };
cout << "Enter the numbers : " << endl;
for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
{
    cin >> arr[x];
}
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
heapSort(arr, n);

cout << "Sorted array is \n";
printArray(arr, n);
}
```

here is the output :
[code output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMtAN.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. If you want to sort only the first 5 elements of the array, simply pass x instead of n  (i.e., 5). The routine does not care whether a few more spare elements are lying behind the ones you use. That said, yes, follow DXZ's advice and use a vector. As an aside, the default initialization of the array with {} is unnecessary: The elements you use are overwritten anyway, the unused ones are, well, unused ...

Answer (score 1):

You can consider std::vector and pass it by reference to your heapify(...) to save memory.